# Android app don't run on the device or emulator?

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my manifest file that my issue is with. Apk installed on the device but I don't see it in the apps and it doesn't launch as it supposed to. I bought this project for 79 dollars but the supplier is now unreachable.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.electricpunch.wallpaper"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1" 
  android:installLocation="preferExternal">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <service
        android:name="com.electricpunch.wallpaper.PlanetWallpaper"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
                                                                    <action                                                                               android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
    </service>           
    <activity
        android:label="@string/settings"
        android:name="com.electricpunch.wallpaper.PlanetSettings"
        android:exported="true"
       >
    </activity>
      <!-- Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|u     iMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any launcher activity... That's why you don't see it in the apps list... See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER

Comment: could you please modify my code brother

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without knowing which Activity was meant to be the launcher activity in the first place.

But you could try modifying this portion of your manifest,

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/settings"
    android:name="com.electricpunch.wallpaper.PlanetSettings"
    android:exported="true"
   >
</activity>
```

to,

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/settings"
    android:name="com.electricpunch.wallpaper.PlanetSettings"
    android:exported="true"
   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Though your best bet is to contact the person you got the app from.

Comment: it worked but it only shows the setting screen nothing more

Answer (score 0):

Your app does not launch because no activtity is decalred to be launch in your manifest.

I don't know which activity you want to use but to be launch from laucher your app should have an activty declared like this :

```
<activity android:name="your.package.YourActivity" >
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: you are very rite my friend but unfortunately it stop working on the start it crashes.